# Is it possible to deploy a WCF service and a WebSite in the same WEBSITE PORTAL from AZURE?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure, wcf-client, azure-storage

I' deploying two services, one of them is a website and the another is a WCF Service for desktop applications.

I have one web site called contoso2.azurewebsites.net and that place I place my web site, but also I would like to deploy my WCF service, the question is...  I need to create another web site service to deploy in it? Or it can be in the same place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can. If you have an ASP.NET web application, you can add some .svc files for your WCF service. They will be deployed as part of your web site. Then you can use your website through http://contoso2.azurewebsites.net/ and use your web service through, let's say http://contoso2.azurewebsites.net/api/ProductService.svc

Comment: Can you tell where do I have to configure my deploy file to indicate the path where I would like to deploy it?

Comment: I don't think you need to change your configuration. You can just add a new folder named 'api' under your web application and add a new WCF service file from VS. Then all of them will be packaged and deployed to azure.

Answer (score 0):

Combining your website and services into one application is possible, but you can also host them in two seperate sites within the same web role.

You basically have to:

1. Create a cspack with multiple sites
2. Map the internal IP address of the machine to a DNS of your choice in the hosts file when the role starts

More details and scripts on my blog: http://thomassmets.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/a-web-frontend-with-a-wcf-backend-in-azure/